# Debug SharePoint Framework with Visual Studio Code

Tags: spfx, office-dev-pnp, visual-studio-code

I am following instructions from below link in order to debug SharePoint Framework,

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode

When I do "gulp serve" i can see local workbanch page and eveything seems to be working fine.

But when I do "gulp serve --nobrowser" followed by F5(run) I see blank chrome with errors in console.

[image]

Below is what I see on debugger mode on chrome browser's console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2507

I found the suggestion in this github issue helpful to solve this exact problem. As noted in the issue, this only occurs for projects using spfx 1.5 and up. To anybody who stumbles here, you will have to launch

https://localhost:5432/workbench

instead of https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html